# Java/ Using Junit 4 gives compilation error

Tags: java, junit

I got a compilation error in my project on package which belongs to Junit (in `org.junit, org.junit.experimental.results, org.junit.internal, org.junit.internal.matchers, org.junit.matchers, org.junit.rules`).

all this classes are under junit package in my project, meaning: `Security/src/org.junit, Security/src/org.junit.experimental.results`, where `Security` is the name of my project. My classes that I wrote are under other package that I define: `Security/src/myPackage/myClass`

In all these classes, it gives a complation error in the import lines, for example:

```
import org.hamcrest.Description cannot be resolved
import org.hamcrest.Matcher cannot be resolved;
import static org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers.containsString cannot be resolved;
```

The checks are going OK (the green/red bar is display, and gives the correct result), but this problem give me an error on all the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JUnit version needs Hamcrest. You should include it in your buildpath or use an older JUnit version.

There are different JUnit packages of the release 4.10:

- junit-4.10.jar: Includes Hamcrest, you should use this.
- junit-dep-4.10.jar: Does NOT include Hamcrest, use this if you already have a hamcrest jar in your buildpath.

Comment: In the first, I import only junit-4.10.jar. But it writes: `The import org.junit cannot be resolved`, `The import junit cannot be resolved`. For that, I install junit-dep-4.10.jar which give me these problems.